# Delaying and expiring a shinyBS::bsTooltip

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

Is it possible to delay a tooltip and expire after a few seconds?

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyBS)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  bsTooltip(id = 'input', title = "Lets delay this appearing for 1s and force disappear after 5s", 
    placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover", options = list(delay = list(show=1000, hide=3000))),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = 'input', label = 'input', choices = c('cats','dogs'))
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)
, server = function(input, output){})
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shinyBS::bsTooltip` fails to properly serialize nested `options` lists in https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/blob/shinyBS3/R/Tooltips_and_Popovers.R#L129

The `options` object ends up looking like `{ delay: "list(show = 1000, hide = 3000)" }`

Unfortunately it looks like shinyBS isn't maintained anymore, or a fix would be worth submitting.

I'll suggest a workaround - using `shinyBS::addTooltip` which does serialize `options` correctly.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    # shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyBS:::shinyBSDep,

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = 'input', label = 'input', choices = c('cats','dogs'))
      ),
      mainPanel()
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    addTooltip(session, id = 'input', title = "Lets delay this appearing for 1s and force disappear after 5s",
               placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover", options = list(delay = list(show=1000, hide=3000)))
  }
)
```

---

Or just using Bootstrap directly.

Comment: Cheers Greg this'll do the job.

Answer (score 3):

I used tipify. So my code was like:

```
tipify(
  element,
  title = "some title",
  options = list("delay" = 1000)
)
```

Problem was: delay has do be numeric but the function **createTooltipOrPopoverOnUI** (https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/blob/shinyBS3/R/Tooltips_and_Popovers.R) will put quotesigns arround all arguments:

```
options = paste0("{'", paste(names(options), options, sep = "': '", collapse = "', '"), "'}")
```

So i did this: im not proud of it but it worked:

```
options = list("delay': 1000, 'it" = "sucks")
```